# Am i adding Rows vs Columns up correctly for a 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays

So I am working on an assignment where I need to sum an array elements first by rows and then by columns.

What I currently have is this:

```
// Sum by Rows
for(int y =0; y< height; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x< width; x++)
    {
        total += array2d[x][y];
    }
}

// Sum by Columns
for(int x =0; x< width; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y< height; y++)
    {
        total += array2d[x][y];
    }
}
```

is this correct? I just want to make sure beforehand as this seems too easy to be the answer.

Comment: Looks good if you should calculate the overall sum. Or do you need to calculate the sum for each row and store/output that?

Comment: the idea is cache timing i have a timer wrapped around it, that shows seconds for it to perform the operation. these are in methods the array is rebuilt after each iteration to be big bigger and thus can see the difference how cache timing is.

Comment: I think a good compiler can optimize it to better cache hit. So, no difference what you're using.

Comment: @Darxval: OK, I understand. Then: yes, you are doing it right. Variant 1 should have more cache misses, variant 2 should access the memory in order with less cache misses.

Answer (score 0):

Few corrections --

```
// Sum by Rows
for(int y =0; y< height; y++)
{
  for(int x = 0; x< width; x++)
  {
    total += array2d[y][x]; // y,x not x,y since you want row(y) to be fix 
                            // for each column in that row
  }
  //total = 0;        //uncomment this if you want sum for each row (store it or print it)
}
```

Change column index also accordingly